# Elegant way of modifying object file' function xref in linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I wondered if there is a way of making a "realy position independent code".

Imagine this situation (the implementation is realy unimportant here.):
You have a file called 'a.c', which contains a simple two functions of `c` code - functin `a` and function `b`, when fnction `a` calls function `b'..

When compiling this simple situation by doing:
`gcc -c -o a.out a.c -fPIC`
And then observing the `text` section, ill see that function `a`, within the assembly, on the place where it calls function `b` - a hold place zeros.
This zeros us we all know, will be simply replaced on runtime acording the value in the relocation table.

Well, here is my question - I found it unnecacery part of the independency.
The reason is, because already before the running, I can determine the distance between `a` and `b`, hence I can rewrite the place holding zeros that meant to be `b` address, with the relative call to the real function.
I found this method of manualy changing the bytes - very long when we tallk about big programs.

So, is there any elegant way to do the same thing I do manually, by a flag from `gcc`/`objdump` or somthing?

Comment: are you sure `-fPIC` is taken into account? and your command line looks suspcious. Can you fix various typos in your question? what is `a.file` ? this isn't C???

Comment: the filling in of the offsets is part of the linking process.  The compiler does not know where the other item will be located

Comment: the point is, if I understand correctly, since both functions are in the same file, it could use relative BSR instead of absolute (which needs linker)

Comment: it's not "process independent code" it's "position-independent code". And what you describe means that -fPIC doesn't work, because the code isn't really position independent. So we're waiting to see your [mcve] because there are too many errors in your question.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre Yes im sure. The fPIC flag make things easier with .got.plt, but doesny solves the relocation "problem". Srry for the typos. Fixed what i could..

Comment: @user3629249 the compiler puts the functions in a fixed order. Then why couldn't it also referring one function referece in the second function to be relative to each other?!

Comment: @mikelbubi. because the linking is the job of the linker

Answer (score 1):

Consider this freestanding **hello.c** for x86-64/AMD64 architecture on Linux:

```
/* Freestanding Hello World example in Linux on x86_64/x86.
 * Compile using
 *      gcc -Wall -O2 -fPIC -pie -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -m64 -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostartfiles hello.c -o hello
*/
#define STDOUT_FILENO 1
#define EXIT_SUCCESS  0

#ifndef __x86_64__
#error  This program only works on x86_64 architecture!
#endif

#define SYS_write    1
#define SYS_exit    60

#define SYSCALL1_NORET(nr, arg1) \
    __asm__ volatile ( "syscall\n\t" \
                     : \
                     : "a" (nr), "D" (arg1) \
                     : "rcx", "r11" )

#define SYSCALL3(retval, nr, arg1, arg2, arg3) \
    __asm__ volatile ( "syscall\n\t" \
                     : "=a" (retval) \
                     : "a" (nr), "D" (arg1), "S" (arg2), "d" (arg3) \
                     : "rcx", "r11" )

static void my_exit(int retval)
{
    SYSCALL1_NORET(SYS_exit, retval);
}

static int my_write(int fd, const void *data, int len)
{
    int retval;

    if (fd == -1 || !data || len < 0)
        return -1;

    SYSCALL3(retval, SYS_write, fd, data, len);

    if (retval < 0)
        return -1;

    return retval;
}

static int my_strlen(const char *str)
{
    int len = 0L;

    if (!str)
        return -1;

    while (*str++)
        len++;

    return len;
}

static int wrout(const char *str)
{
    if (str && *str)
        return my_write(STDOUT_FILENO, str, my_strlen(str));
    else
        return 0;
}

void _start(void)
{
    const char *msg = "Hello, world!\n";
    wrout(msg);
    my_exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Note that it fulfills OP's scenario: `_start()` calls `wrout()`, which calls `my_strlen()` and `my_write()`.

(Why freestanding, without all the niceties of the standard C library? Because the standard library is not compiled with `-fPIC` and `-pie`, so it'd have to be dynamically linked to the standard library; and those calls would have relocations, clouding my point. Being freestanding, we get a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, that yields clear, unambiguous results.)

Compile it using

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -fPIC -pie -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -m64 -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostartfiles hello.c -o hello
```

and run using `./hello`. It prints out "Hello, world!" as it should.

Next, examine it using `objdump -x hello`:

```
hello:     file format elf64-x86-64
hello
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000150:
HAS_SYMS, DYNAMIC, D_PAGED
start address 0x0000000000000340

Program Header:
    PHDR off    0x0000000000000040 vaddr 0x0000000000000040 paddr 0x0000000000000040 align 2**3
         filesz 0x00000000000001f8 memsz 0x00000000000001f8 flags r-x
  INTERP off    0x0000000000000238 vaddr 0x0000000000000238 paddr 0x0000000000000238 align 2**0
         filesz 0x000000000000001c memsz 0x000000000000001c flags r--
    LOAD off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000000000 paddr 0x0000000000000000 align 2**21
         filesz 0x00000000000003d0 memsz 0x00000000000003d0 flags r-x
    LOAD off    0x0000000000000f30 vaddr 0x0000000000200f30 paddr 0x0000000000200f30 align 2**21
         filesz 0x00000000000000d0 memsz 0x00000000000000d0 flags rw-
 DYNAMIC off    0x0000000000000f30 vaddr 0x0000000000200f30 paddr 0x0000000000200f30 align 2**3
         filesz 0x00000000000000d0 memsz 0x00000000000000d0 flags rw-
    NOTE off    0x0000000000000254 vaddr 0x0000000000000254 paddr 0x0000000000000254 align 2**2
         filesz 0x0000000000000024 memsz 0x0000000000000024 flags r--
EH_FRAME off    0x0000000000000388 vaddr 0x0000000000000388 paddr 0x0000000000000388 align 2**2
         filesz 0x0000000000000014 memsz 0x0000000000000014 flags r--
   STACK off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000000000 paddr 0x0000000000000000 align 2**4
         filesz 0x0000000000000000 memsz 0x0000000000000000 flags rw-
   RELRO off    0x0000000000000f30 vaddr 0x0000000000200f30 paddr 0x0000000000200f30 align 2**0
         filesz 0x00000000000000d0 memsz 0x00000000000000d0 flags r--

Dynamic Section:
  GNU_HASH             0x0000000000000278
  STRTAB               0x0000000000000320
  SYMTAB               0x00000000000002a8
  STRSZ                0x0000000000000019
  SYMENT               0x0000000000000018
  DEBUG                0x0000000000000000
  FLAGS_1              0x0000000008000000

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .interp       0000001c  0000000000000238  0000000000000238  00000238  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .note.gnu.build-id 00000024  0000000000000254  0000000000000254  00000254  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .gnu.hash     00000030  0000000000000278  0000000000000278  00000278  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .dynsym       00000078  00000000000002a8  00000000000002a8  000002a8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .dynstr       00000019  0000000000000320  0000000000000320  00000320  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .text         00000037  0000000000000340  0000000000000340  00000340  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  6 .rodata       0000000f  0000000000000377  0000000000000377  00000377  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  7 .eh_frame_hdr 00000014  0000000000000388  0000000000000388  00000388  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  8 .eh_frame     00000030  00000000000003a0  00000000000003a0  000003a0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  9 .dynamic      000000d0  0000000000200f30  0000000000200f30  00000f30  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 10 .comment      00000035  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00001000  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000238 l    d  .interp            0000000000000000 .interp
0000000000000254 l    d  .note.gnu.build-id 0000000000000000 .note.gnu.build-id
0000000000000278 l    d  .gnu.hash          0000000000000000 .gnu.hash
00000000000002a8 l    d  .dynsym            0000000000000000 .dynsym
0000000000000320 l    d  .dynstr            0000000000000000 .dynstr
0000000000000340 l    d  .text              0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000377 l    d  .rodata            0000000000000000 .rodata
0000000000000388 l    d  .eh_frame_hdr      0000000000000000 .eh_frame_hdr
00000000000003a0 l    d  .eh_frame          0000000000000000 .eh_frame
0000000000200f30 l    d  .dynamic           0000000000000000 .dynamic
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment           0000000000000000 .comment
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*              0000000000000000 hello.c
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*              0000000000000000 
0000000000200f30 l     O .dynamic           0000000000000000 _DYNAMIC
0000000000000388 l       .eh_frame_hdr      0000000000000000 __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000201000 l     O .dynamic           0000000000000000 _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000340 g     F .text              0000000000000037 _start
0000000000201000 g       .dynamic           0000000000000000 __bss_start
0000000000201000 g       .dynamic           0000000000000000 _edata
0000000000201000 g       .dynamic           0000000000000000 _end
```

and it has only the basic symbols. You can even strip it, `strip --strip-unneeded hello`, after which it has no symbols at all. (The start address does not need to be a symbol in ELF files.)  Looking at the assembly, `objdump -d hello`,

```
hello:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000340 <_start>:
 340:  48 8d 0d 31 00 00 00   lea    0x31(%rip),%rcx        # 378 <_start+0x38>
 347:  31 d2                  xor    %edx,%edx
 349:  0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00   nopl   0x0(%rax)
 350:  48 83 c1 01            add    $0x1,%rcx
 354:  83 c2 01               add    $0x1,%edx
 357:  80 79 ff 00            cmpb   $0x0,-0x1(%rcx)
 35b:  75 f3                  jne    350 <_start+0x10>
 35d:  b8 01 00 00 00         mov    $0x1,%eax
 362:  48 8d 35 0e 00 00 00   lea    0xe(%rip),%rsi        # 377 <_start+0x37>
 369:  89 c7                  mov    %eax,%edi
 36b:  0f 05                  syscall 
 36d:  31 ff                  xor    %edi,%edi
 36f:  b8 3c 00 00 00         mov    $0x3c,%eax
 374:  0f 05                  syscall 
 376:  c3                     retq
```

and you'll see all addressing is relative to `%rip`, including the conditional jumps. For example, `75 f3` encodes a jump 13 bytes before the start of the next opcode (0xF3 = -13).

If you omit optimization (`-O2`), GCC tries to be helpful and includes the *local* symbols in the ELF file; you can remove those using `strip --strip-unneeded hello`.

So, when you compile to an object file without optimization, `gcc -Wall -fPIC -pie -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -m64 -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostartfiles -c hello.c`, and examine the resulting `hello.o` using `objdump -x hello.o`, you'll se both the local symbols (`l` in the second column),

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*              0000000000000000 hello.c
0000000000000000 l    d  .text              0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data              0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss               0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l     F .text              0000000000000016 my_exit
0000000000000016 l     F .text              000000000000004e my_write
0000000000000064 l     F .text              0000000000000039 my_strlen
000000000000009d l     F .text              0000000000000046 wrout
0000000000000000 l    d  .rodata            0000000000000000 .rodata
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack    0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame          0000000000000000 .eh_frame
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment           0000000000000000 .comment
00000000000000e3 g     F .text              000000000000002c _start
```

and that there is one relocation record for `.text`,

```
RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
00000000000000ee R_X86_64_PC32     .rodata-0x0000000000000004
```

which being of `R_X86_64_PC32` type, is instruction pointer relative 32-bit constant. When linked into a binary (executable or library), these relocations will be applied, and the final binary will be position independent.

The only symbols needed in the file are those that need to be accessible from outside, excluding `_start`, whose address is stored as the start address in the ELF file.  If a function or a global variable is not needed outside a compilation unit, you mark them `static`.  Then, we tell the compiler to generate position independent code (`-fPIC`) and a position independent executable (`-pie`). I personally always enable warnings and optimization (`-Wall -O2`), but that's up to you.

So, the answer to OP's question as to *"how to do this"*:

1. Use `static` for all functions and global variables that do not need to be accessible outside the current compilation unit.
2. Compile the object and/or binary with `-fPIC` `-pie`.  This should avoid the need of runtime relocations, and use `%rip`-relative addressing or similar on all architectures that support it.
3. Optionally, strip unneeded symbols from the binary using `strip --strip-unneeded`. This does not affect relocations, but makes the binary smaller, by removing the unneeded symbol information.